# Angular method works in ngOnIt but doesn't work properly on button click

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using **Facebook SDK for Javascript with ng2-facebook-sdk**

And I am facing weird issue can someone help me here.

In the below code I am initializing the options for the Facebook SDK and initiating the login for the users but When I put the code in `ngOnIt()` it works always (Working always means: Users will get the pop up for entering the facebook username and password and once successful login the popup closes and comes back to the main page) But this **is not preferable as User opens pages it forces user to login using Facebook**

but When I put the code under some method outside ngOnI it doesn't work(Here Popup appears and once users enters credentials and submit the popup becomes white and remains and it doesn't come back to main page)

To trigger the method I have used below HTML

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" (click)="loginWithFacebook()">Login</button>
</form>
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FacebookService, LoginResponse, InitParams } from 'ngx-facebook';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private fb: FacebookService, private rt: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    loginWithFacebook() {
        const initParams: InitParams = {
        appId: 'xxx',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.11'
    };
    this.fb.init(initParams);
    this.fb.login()
        .then((response: LoginResponse) => console.log(response))
        .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

**Works**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FacebookService, LoginResponse, InitParams } from 'ngx-facebook';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private fb: FacebookService, private rt: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        const initParams: InitParams = {
            appId: 'xxx',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.11'
        };

        this.fb.init(initParams);
        this.fb.login()
            .then((response: LoginResponse) => console.log(response))
            .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use type="button"

Comment: @DmitryGrinko Awesome !! It Worked.  Any reason why not to use `type=submit`

Comment: Wow! I have added answer to allow you close the question

Comment: ngOnIt > ngOnInit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `type="button"`

`type="submit"` buttons are used to submit forms. If you want to create a custom button and then customize the behavior using JavaScript, you need to use , or better still, a  element.

[read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit)